# InputMismatchException when using Sacnner nextLine for String

Tags: java, exception, inputmismatchexception

This is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class student
{
    String name;
    int age;
    float cgpa;
}
public class getdata
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n=in.nextInt();
        student[] s=new student[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                s[i]=new student();
                s[i].name=in.nextLine();
                in.nextLine();
                s[i].age=in.nextInt();
                s[i].cgpa=in.nextFloat();
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Name\tAge\tCGPA\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i].name+"\t"+s[i].age+"\t"+s[i].cgpa+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

compiling the program gave no problem. but when executing and i try to input a string space , it takes the string as two separate strings and assigns all other values of one to be null. for eg if i enter

```
mike hannigan
5
6.5
```

The output is

```
mike 0 0.0
hannigan 5 6.5
```

i tried getting the string with only a single `in.nextLine();` but that causes the string to be taken as null(Throws InputMismatchException). with try and catch block

[image: with try block]

and without the try block, this is the output i get

[image]

Comment: It's because `nextInt` and `nextFloat` don't consume the newline character, so the subsequent `nextLine` won't capture what you expect it to. I'm sure there's a duplicate that explains this somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to always scan the entire line as String and convert it to required data types using parse methods. Please see below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    student[] s=new student[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            s[i]=new student();
            s[i].name=in.nextLine();
            s[i].age=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            s[i].cgpa=Float.parseFloat(in.nextLine());

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Name\tAge\tCGPA\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s[i].name+"\t"+s[i].age+"\t"+s[i].cgpa+"\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the very common mistake in understanding `Scanner`.

Calling `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()`, or most other `nextXxx()` methods will leave the newline following the number unprocessed.

A subsequent call to any of the `nextXxx()` methods, *other than* `nextLine()`, will automatically skip that newline, as being whitespace between tokens.

However, `nextLine()` does **not** skip leading whitespace, so calling `nextLine()` after any other `nextXxx()` method, will return an empty string (or rather whatever is on the rest of the line following the last token).

So, when *mixing* `nextXxx()` calls with `nextLine()` calls, you have to flush (discard) the end of the previous line by calling `nextLine()` first.

This means your code should be:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine(); // Ignore rest of line after int
student[] s = new student[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s[i] = new student();
    s[i].name = in.nextLine();
    s[i].age = in.nextInt();
    s[i].cgpa = in.nextFloat();
    in.nextLine(); // Ignore rest of line after float
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Name\tAge\tCGPA");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(s[i].name + "\t" + s[i].age + "\t" + s[i].cgpa);
}
```

Better yet, do what the [answer by @JaganathanNanthakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38320030/5221149) says: Always use `nextLine()` and parse the number yourself.

Comment: It's very common, so there's actually a canonical answer for it (which I linked)

Comment: @4castle You're right, I forgot what it was.

Comment: Nothing against the answer of course. It's good to have a specific solution for the OP to get the idea.

Comment: @4castle That canonical answer is already in my favs, since I see these kind of mistakes too often. I just forgot I had it there. Thanks for reminding me. ;-)