# Understand Java Scanner weirdness

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm working on code for school and ran into a problem while reading user input.  I made a new class for testing to see if it is my code around it and it's not.  Here is the simplified code.

```
    import java.util.*;
public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in) ;
      String fullname = kb.nextLine();
      int age = kb.nextInt();
      String program = kb.nextLine();
    * int number = kb.nextInt();
      System.out.println(fullname);
      System.out.println(age);
      System.out.println(program);
      System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

The following error comes up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at practice.main(practice.java:8)
```

I've marked where the error is incurring.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

What I've tried so far:
- Added `kb.nextLine()` after the first `kb.nextLine()`
- Tried to reset the scanner after each input

Comment: Can you share the input that causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in) ;
  String fullname = kb.nextLine();
  int age = kb.nextInt();
  kb.nextLine();
  String program = kb.nextLine();
  int number = kb.nextInt();

  kb.nextLine();
  System.out.println(fullname);
  System.out.println(age);
  System.out.println(program);
  System.out.println(number);
```

Ref: [InputMismatchException when using Sacnner nextLine for String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319917/inputmismatchexception-when-using-sacnner-nextline-for-string)

Comment: "works fine" ok, but why does it work? What is the significant change? A good answer spells it out, rather than just dumping code and saying "this will work".

Comment: You are right hence I have added reference. Pretty good explanation there.