# sc.nextLine() throws InputMismatchException while sc.next() doesn't

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

In the following code snippet, scanner is throwing `InputMismatchException` after I input the value for coach and press enter. However if I use `coach=sc.next();` , no such exception is thrown.

```
void accept() {
        System.out.println("Enter name , mobile number and coach for the customer and also the amount of ticket.");
        name=sc.nextLine();
        mobno= sc.nextLong();
        coach=sc.nextLine();
        amt=sc.nextInt();
    }
```

I expected no exception in both the cases however I cannot understand why the exception is thrown only for `sc.nextLine();`.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the exact input?

Comment: Your error description and debugging done so far aren't very detailed, [but this may be a case of nextLine() being skipped after your nextLong() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `sc.nextLine()` to read the coach, it encounters the newline character left by the previous `nextLong()` call. As a result, **it reads an empty line** (interprets the newline character as an input line) and proceeds without letting you enter the *coach name*.

My suggestion is always use `nextLine()` and convert to the wanted `Class`, like this:

```java
void accept() {
    System.out.println("Enter name , mobile number and coach for the customer and also the amount of ticket.");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    
    // Cast long value
    mobno = Long.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
    
    coach = sc.nextLine();
    
    // Cast int value
    amt = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
}
```

**Check this out:**

- [InputMismatchException when using Sacnner nextLine for String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319917/inputmismatchexception-when-using-sacnner-nextline-for-string)
- [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

But you can do this way too:

```java
void accept() {
    System.out.println("Enter name, mobile number, coach for the customer, and also the amount of ticket.");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    mobno = sc.nextLong();

    // Consume the remaining newline character in the input buffer
    sc.nextLine();

    coach = sc.nextLine();
    amt = sc.nextInt();
}
```